# Laravel nova - use action to allow multiple download

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In laravel Nova 2.0

> To initiate a file download after the action is executed, you may use
>   the Action::download method. The download method accepts the URL of
>   the file to be downloaded as its first argument, and the desired name
>   of the file as its second argument:

```
return Action::download('https://example.com/invoice.pdf', 'Invoice.pdf');
```

in Action handle method

```
 public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        foreach ( $models as $model ) {
            return Action::download($model->document_link, $model->document_title);
        }
    }
```

now this will download the last one in loop, how to allow download all in the loop?

**Update**

One option will be using Zipper or something to create zip of all the downloadable files selected and then download it, but I would like it if we can allow a queue of downloads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to download multiple files using

```
return Action::download()
```

A work around could be to create a zipped archive containing all files and present this archive example:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    foreach ( $models as $model ) {
       $this->addTozip($model) // some function to build an archive
    }
    return Action::download('https://example.com/invoice.zip', 'Invoice.zip');
}
```